# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac {\ln x}{1-x^2} \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found this question in a reference book:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac {\ln x}{1-x^2} \mathrm{d}x $$
Can Anyone give me Idea how do I begin solving this?

Comment: You need the knoweledge of a primitive in $(0,1)$ for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ (that can be found quite easily) and for $\ln x$ (a.k.a $x\ln x-x$).

Then, you can integrate by parts (integrate $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$  and derive $\ln x$) to calculate $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1^-}\int_0^\alpha\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx$

Comment: No Idea, Can you begin solving??? So that I get Idea?

Comment: My bad, it does not work as smoothly as I had hoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:  Work formally using $1/(1-x^2)=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots$.  Integrate $\int_0^1 x^{2k}\ln x\,dx$ by parts.  At some point it helps to know that $1+{1\over4}+{1\over9}+{1\over16}+\cdots={\pi^2\over6}$ (but even then there's a bit more work to do).

Comment: Thank you , I have figured it out